# Does iterator provide improvement when used together with values_list?

Tags: django, django-orm

Recently I saw code which used together `iterator()` and `values_list()`. Does it make sence to use them both together? Will it improve speed or memory usage?

Sample code:

```
Customer.objects.values_list("pk", flat=True).iterator()
```

Comment: `iterator()` will reduce memory usage since results will be loaded in chunks, it probably won't affect the overall speed though since the same amount of data is being loaded. It really depends on what you will be doing when iterating over the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `value_list()` returns a `QuerySet` that returns dictionaries[[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values).

> `QuerySets` are lazy – the act of creating a `QuerySet` doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

You can see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) to check when a `queryset` is evaluated.

In fact by creating a `queryset` django doesn't hit the database until it is being evaluated (by something like `iterator`).

as `Iterator()` read the results without caching will result to better performance in situations we need to access the objects just onece, and it's not related to the kind of `querysets`